# How to import a public PGP key from a keyserver without leaving Evolution?

Tags: gnupg, evolution

Situation is this:

I get PGP-encrypted mails that I can decrypt, and signed messages; however, I can't seem to find a button within Evolution to import the sender's public key from any keyserver.

Am I missing something, or is it up to me as user to get sufficiently fed up with manually executing

```
gpg2 --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --search {sender's email adress}
gpg2 --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys {sender's key ID}
```

and fix evolution itself by ... writing a gui button for this?

Comment: Does the information here help? https://superuser.com/questions/1491132/how-to-automatically-obtain-keys-in-evolution-for-e-mail-recipients-key-discov You would still need to configure GnuPG outside of Evolution one time.