# How to automatically obtain keys in Evolution for e-mail recipients? (key discovery)

Tags: email, pgp, gnupg

I am using the PIM [Evolution](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution) 3.22.6 for e-mail and contacts. For encrypting e-mails gpg (GnuPG 2.1.18) is used by Evolution.

*How can I configure my system such as when I compose an e-mail the PGP key for the recipients are automatically retrieved from key servers and added to my keyring?*

For example when I try to send an e-mail to a recipient, which is not in my keyring I get the following error message: `gpg: <edward-en@fsf.org>: skipped: No public key`

In case I run - outside of Evolution - `gpg --search-keys edward-en@fsf.org` a key is successfully found. Is there any way to tell Evolution to deal with the  search?

Comment: I have reported an [issue to request that feature](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution-data-server/issues/170).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That interoperability issue](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evolution-list/2019-October/msg00055.html) has been *[resolved since GnuPG 2.2.19](https://dev.gnupg.org/T4726#131143)*. You still need to [configure GnuPG to automatically retrieve keys for encryption](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Configuration-Options.html#index-auto_002dkey_002dlocate). This can be done in a configuration file (`~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`):

```
keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80
auto-key-locate keyserver
```

In order to use that version with the current Debian stable distribution, [Debian Backports](https://backports.debian.org/) can be used.

Answer (score 0):

[It should be working solely by setting up GnuPG](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evolution-list/2019-October/msg00052.html) (to use `auto-key-locate keyserver`). There seems to be an [interoperability issue](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evolution-list/2019-October/msg00055.html) with Evolution 3.22.6 and GnuPG (tested with 2.1.18, 2.2.12, 2.2.17).

As a workaround an adapter can installed to intercept Evolution's call of GnuPG. There is a small [script for this purpose](https://gist.github.com/dhebbeker/36b3da99ea1a520ffd9a6ed9b3db7880). The quintessence is:

```bash
temporaryFile=`mktemp` 
trap "rm $temporaryFile" EXIT # remove file when finished
printf " %q" "$@" | sed -E 's| -r \\<(\S+@\S+)\\>| -r \1|' > $temporaryFile
xargs --arg-file=$temporaryFile gpg # Run GnuPG with modified arguments
```

To install, use `dconf-editor` to set `org.gnome.evolution-data-server.camel-gpg-binary` to the absolute path of that script.